# How to create folder in mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing one MVC4 application and hosting in IIS web server.

I want to upload and save few files in folder called `UploadedFile` inside `F` drive. 
I wrote below piece of code to create folder however it does not work

```
if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/F:/UploadedFile")))
{  
  System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/F:/UploadedFile"));
}
```

When i am hosting  to IIS i will keep all the published files inside `inetpub`(files like dll(bin),css,js etc). But i am planning to keep pdf files uploaded by user in F drive.

Is this good practice to keep files outside `c` drive? can some one give some suggestions please.

Comment: No rpob keeping files anywhere. Just create virual directory and map it with website

Comment: i found this and worked   string folderName = @"F:\UploadedFile";
                        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(folderName))
                        {
                            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(folderName);
                        }

Comment: However this line of code is not working  string folderName = @"F:\UploadedFile";
                                    byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(folderName + filename);

Comment: _"it does not work"_ - read [ask] and provide a proper problem description and share your research for that error. Also, you don't have to map absolute paths. When running in a web server running as a Windows Service (e.g. IIS), you also don't have mapped network drives, so `F:` must be a local drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with keeping your files outside of the web folder, as long as you take care of setting up security and ACL's properly. This stuff is not trivial to do and you may end with security issues if you don't configure it correctly.

In your case I think you are getting a wrong path when trying to get the data from the file.

In this line:

```
System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(folderName + filename);
```

folderName + filename will return `@"F:\UploadedFile<filename>"`. E.g.: `@"F:\UploadedFilefile1.docx"` so you'll get an error as it's an invalid path.

In order to avoid this kind of errors you should use `Path.Combine`.

```
using System.IO;

//this will return @"F:\UploadedFile\file1.docx"
var fullFileName = Path.Combine(folderName, fileName);
var bytes=  System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fullFileName);

//do something with your file.
```

Hope this helps!